# Clojure - require scope rules

Tags: clojure, require

When using Clojure `require` as a function, what are the scoping rules, and can they be changed ?

For instance, when `require` is inside a function, or is there a `with-scope` or something similar to control `require` behaviour ? Can a `require` shadow another ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `require` more than once will not have any effect unless you force it with something like `:reload`, so there's no shadowing that goes on. I believe you can call it anywhere (just like any other function) and it will have no special behaviour relative to the call site.